# Euler Equation with Dirichlet condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Some references said the incompressible Euler equation is not well posed with Dirichlet boundary condition :

$$u_t+u\cdot\nabla u+\nabla p=0$$
$$\nabla\cdot u=0$$
$$u=0 \ \ \text{on}\ \partial\Omega$$

Why is this?

Comment: See [this](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=PN5jfBzvOmsC&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=incompressible+euler+equation+ill+posed&source=bl&ots=afE39mRYhv&sig=N_frBIO68PKvu5-YeFTAwa34Itc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLgpCxto_LAhWBmJQKHZK4AoUQ6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=incompressible%20euler%20equation%20ill%20posed&f=false).

Comment: @Mattos  Sorry, I cannot see boundary value problem for Euler equation on this book? Thank you for your help.